# Imageview in a listview - Height is bugged?

Tags: android, xml, listview

I am having a listview but i have problem
i have the main.xml file, which contains a Listview:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/gradient"
android:gravity="center"
android:padding="1pt">

<ListView android:id="@+id/ListView01" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Then, i have a custom listview file called listview.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:background="@android:color/transparent"
  android:cacheColorHint="#00000000">

<TextView android:gravity="center" android:textColor="#ffffff"
android:background="#0097D0" android:text="Overskrift"
android:id="@+id/tvOverskrift" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textStyle="bold" />

<ImageView android:id="@+id/ivBillede" android:scaleType="fitXY"
android:padding="2px" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/test"/>

<TextView android:gravity="center" android:textColor="#ED2025" 
android:text="Dato" android:id="@+id/tvDato" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textStyle="normal"/>

<TextView android:gravity="left" android:textColor="#000000" android:text="Indledning"
android:id="@+id/tvIndledning" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textStyle="normal"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

the bitmap in the imagview i am getting is from a URL.

By that code, i am getting is this:
http://img585.imageshack.us/img585/5665/unavngivetv.png

I am getting too much space in the height as you see

Comment: Remove this line from Imageview
 android:gravity="fill"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to ask
>   you to check that image in photo shop,
>   For Instance, If i had an image whose
>   size is 250 x 250, but the image
>   appears only 150x150 , means the image
>   size is only 250 x 250, so pls make
>   sure what is the size of image, i hope
>   you had understand my
>   point............

Comment: That's weird.. It makes the two textviews in the bottom go up to the textview at above, they get kinda mixed up (textviews in the bottom become placed OVER the textview from above).. The picture is under.. and the space remains...

Comment: btw. i removed android:scaleType="fitXY" from the imageview. thats when the space occurs. when fitxy is enabled i am not getting the space, it just fills the space out with the picture by extending it, but the picture looks wrong that way

Comment: @Abdullah Gheith: May i know Why you are using gravity parameter as fill instead of center or bottom , like that??????????????????

Comment: Because i got crazy about it not working so i started adding alot of random stuff. but i removed it and it still doesnt work.

Comment: @Abdullah Gheith: can you pls post that output, so that i can see exactly and can identify any issue on that image, in the meanwhile, i would ask you to check that image in photo shop, For Instance, If i had an image whose size is 250 x 250, but the image appears only 150x150 , means the image size is only 250 x 250, so pls make sure what is the size of image, i hope you had understand my point............

Comment: I just noticed the picture is 581x301. I didn't know it was that big.. I changed the resolution to 300x155 and it worked fine. thanks for your time. (Maybe it wasnt working before because i am using a x10 mini pro)

Comment: @Abdullah Gheith: hmmmmmm, Welcome,: To gain reputation, and make others to answer your question, vote it and accepts the good answers of your questions

Comment: @Abdullah Gheith: I had edited, my answers, because in future, if people had same problem , then they can make sure this criteria is not going in wrong way....

Comment: Okay. For others having the same issue: As i am retrieving my images from URL, what i did was i put a php file that resizes the image so i can both have an image at the size i want, but i also keep a copy on my server instead. then i use the image i saved on my  a bit complicated but it works